# Filter rows of a data frame where all the specified columns has null values in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame as shown below

```
ID    type      C1      D1    C2    D2
1     Small     2       NaN   NaN   3
2     Medium    NaN     7     2     9
3     Micro     NaN     NaN   NaN   NaN
4     Medium    2       3     5     4
5     Small     NaN     2     NaN   NaN
6     Small     NaN     NaN   NaN   NaN
```

From the above, I would like to filter the rows where C1, D1, C2, and D2 all have NaN or null values.

Expected Output:

```
ID    type      C1      D1    C2    D2
3     Micro     NaN     NaN   NaN   NaN
6     Small     NaN     NaN   NaN   NaN
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
m=df[['C1', 'D1', 'C2', 'D2']].isna().all(1)
#Finally:
df[m]
#OR
df.loc[m]
```

OR

If there are more columns like these then you can use:

```
m=df.filter(regex='^C\d+|^D\d+').isna().all(1)
#Finally:
df[m]
#OR
df.loc[m]
```

output:

```
    ID  type    C1      D1      C2      D2
2   3   Micro   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
5   6   Small   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
```